# OOP Implementing Clear for Binary Tree - do all nodes need to disown their children for proper GC, or does only the root node need to be disowned?

Tags: java, data-structures, garbage-collection, binary-tree

I wrote an example code about binary tree. Adding and traversing nodes to the binary tree both start from the root node. What should I do if I want to empty the whole binary tree? Use clear1 method or clear2 method? The clear1 method only sets the root node to null. The clear2 method traverses each node and then sets each node to null. It seems that both can achieve the goal of clearing. I don't know the difference between the two. If clear1 is used, I don't know whether the node that is not set to null will affect garbage collection

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;

public class BinaryTree<T> {

public int size;

public Node root;

private Queue<Node> queue;

public class Node {
    public T value;
    public Node leftNode;
    public Node rightNode;

    private Node(T value, Node leftNode, Node rightNode) {
        this.value = value;
        this.leftNode = leftNode;
        this.rightNode = rightNode;
    }
}


public void add(T addValue) {
    Node node = new Node(addValue, null, null);
    if (null == root) {
        root = node;
        queue = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.offer(node);
    } else {
        Node queNode = queue.peek();
        if (null == queNode.leftNode) {
            queNode.leftNode = node;
            queue.offer(queNode.leftNode);
        } else if (null == queNode.rightNode) {
            queNode.rightNode = node;
            queue.poll();
            queue.offer(queNode.rightNode);
        }
    }
    size++;
}


/**
 * Postorder Traversal
 */
public List<T> postTraverse() {
    return postTraverse(new ArrayList<>(), root);
}

private List<T> postTraverse(List<T> list, Node node) {
    if (list.size() != size && null != node) {
        postTraverse(list, node.leftNode);
        postTraverse(list, node.rightNode);
        list.add(node.value);
    }
    return list;
}

/**
 * clear Binary Tree method1
 */
public void clear1() {
    queue = null;
    size = 0;
    root = null;
}

/**
 * clear Binary Tree method2
 */
public void clear2() {
    queue = null;
    clear2(root);
    size = 0;
}

private void clear2(Node node) {
    if (null != node) {
        clear2(node.leftNode);
        clear2(node.rightNode);
        node = null;
    }
}
}
```

test:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    BinaryTree<String> binaryTree = new BinaryTree<>();
    binaryTree.add("A");
    binaryTree.add("B");
    binaryTree.add("C");
    binaryTree.add("D");
    binaryTree.add("E");
    binaryTree.add("F");
    binaryTree.add("G");
    binaryTree.add("H");
    binaryTree.add("i");
    binaryTree.add("j");
    binaryTree.add("k");
    binaryTree.add("L");
    binaryTree.add("M");
    binaryTree.add("N");
    binaryTree.add("O");

    System.out.println(binaryTree.postTraverse());
    binaryTree.clear1();
}
```

Comment: "Clearing a tree" is always(!) O(1) operation: `root = null;`!  (The rest is up to GC )

Comment: There are different strategies for implementing garbage collection and I'm not aware of any Java language/JVM specs mandating use of a specific strategy (but I haven't researched this so I don't actually know). From my limited understanding of those approaches, all of them should support cleaning up the whole tree after your `clear1`. Writing up a high quality answer to this question would mean explaining all those garbage collectors (a lot of work!) _unless_ you specify in your question that you don't care to get an answer to that level of detail (which you haven't).

Comment: Commentary on your code: you have a leaky abstraction: `Node.leftNode` and `Node.rightNode` are `public` and not `final`, which means anyone who can refer to them can change them. You probably don't want that because it means people can make the Nodes go out of sync with the `BinaryTree.size` and `BinaryTree.queue`. The same comment goes for `BinaryTree.size`, which is public and not final. To prevent those bad usages, make those fields private and expose them with getters instead.

Comment: As an ammendment to my first comment about garbage collection, garbage collectors will not collect Nodes which are still being referenced by _anything_- not just other than parent nodes. So if you want Nodes to become defunct when the `BinaryTree` they belong to is `clear()`ed, then you _should_ use `clear2`.

Comment: This shows that there are other considerations other than just garbage collection in the choice between `clear1` and `clear2`. Ie. should nodes belonging to a tree still hold useful information after the tree they belong to is cleared? That's for you to decide as the designer of your tree interface.

Answer (score 1):

Just setting the `root` to `null` is the most efficient solution.

> I don't know whether the node that is not set to `null` will affect garbage collection.

Assuming that nothing else has a reference to any of the `Node` objects (which should be the case if the code is implemented correctly), then setting `root` to `null` renders the entire tree of `Node` objects unreachable.  They will typically be collected in the next new space collection.

Traversing the tree and clearing all of the references will achieve nothing, and will actually waste time.

---

For all existing Java GC implementations (with the possible exception of some "fall-back" collectors) minimal work is actually performed on heap nodes that are not reachable.  The GC does not need to mark them, or visit them to check mark bits.  Instead, after copying all of the *reachable* objects out of the "space" being collected, it erases the rest by (effectively) writing zeros to the entire space<sup>1</sup>.

Since the unreachable tree is not going to be traversed, marked or looked at in any other way by the GC, any changes your code makes to the nodes in `clear2()` are pointless.  Indeed, such changes could hinder the GC.  For example, with G1GC the post-write barrier for the assignments could cause "cards" to be unnecessarily marked as dirty, delaying the collection of the objects that they cover.

---

<sup>1 - Have you ever wondered why they defined the default values for primitive and reference fields to be `false` or zero and `null`?  One reason is because they are all represented as binary zeros.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Use the first method.  There is no benefit to clear2 it just does a lot of useless work.

Even if the GC did need to traverse the tree (which it generally does not), it wouldn't be doing any more work than your own code in clear2, so just do the minimal operation to update your tree and leave the GC to do it's job.  The GC code is some of the most optimized areas of the JVM, don't try to outsmart it.

Comment: I've added a bit more to address that.